# One Page Bootstrap Page is not rendering properly in IE 11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

I have built a one page, responsive site using Bootstrap. As others have encountered, it looks great in Mac & Win FF, Mac & Win Chrome, Safari, and even Win IE 8 & 9.

It's just when we try it on IE 11 that it fails.

The text is running the full width of the page, though those pieces of text are properly placed in their containers and rows and so forth. The navigation ought to be inline but it ends up stacked vertically.

I'm making the calls for html5shiv, respond, ie=edge.

I have been racking my brain, trying all sorts of different things, deleting some code here & there to see if that's the problem, but haven't found a solution yet.

I'm hoping I've missed a totally obvious issue. My code is really simple; the page is a simple landing page, almost bare bones. It won't be up too long but it will be really important next week.

Can anyone offer and help or pointers?

Comment: Yes, we can help if you can show us the code.

Comment: I was able to get the code up on my own server to test externally.
 
This is the link to that page: http://www.schleitheim.com/design/projects/SBTPG/index.html
 
So, should be no restrictions to the files.